# Density plot not showing up in R

Tags: r

I am unsure why my density plot isn't showing up in Rstudio. When I run the code it just says null device.. could you help me check if perhaps there is an error in my code?

```
 plot(density(data$newc[data$young==1]), col="red",lty=1,xlab="Newc",main="Newc and 
 Young")
 lines(density(data$newc[data$young==0]), col="blue",lty=1)
 legend("topright", legend=c("Age<40", "Age>=40"), col=c("red", "blue"), lty=c(1,1))
 dev.off()
```

Comment: For starters `dev.off()` closes the plot window, possibly faster than you can see it. If that is not the problem, try printing `head(data$newc[data$young==1])` and `head(data$newc[data$young==0])` to see what your data look like. For more suggestions, you will have to provide some actual data.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much! So what if I just delete dev.off()? I did try removing the dev.off() and yes I get the density plot now. But without the dev.off(), is my code still correct? What I mean is, the density plot that is now showing is correct right? Even without the dev.off()? My apologies I am a student very new to R and this is part of the assignment.

Comment: `dev.off()` is used when you open a graphics device to capture the plot and save it to your compute as a ".pdf", ".jpeg", ".tiff", etc. You open the device, e.g `png("MyPlot.png")` and then close the device and save the file with `dev.off()`. If it is in your code, you may be missing the line before the `plot()` command that opened the device. If you are supposed to turn in a copy of the plot, you should add that line to the beginning. If you are just creating the plot to view it in R, you do not need `dev.off()`. Just close the plot window manually when you are finished.